# config directory when using sbt-native-packager

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'd like to ask about reasoning behind the fact, that the sbt-native-packager plugin creates a symlink /etc/ -> /usr/share//conf (instead of really putting files there and somehow specifying in the app where to look for them)?

In particular how does it influence update/uninstall+install process? Are the configs somehow preserved (for example for debian with java_server architecture setting)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'd like to ask about reasoning behind the fact, that the sbt-native-packager plugin creates a symlink /etc/ -> /usr/share//conf

Keeping everything in one place. You have your application directory which contains everything and then you just link from the OS-specific folders to the according directories in your application folder.

> Are the configs somehow preserved

Yes indeed. You can try it out with a simple play application. Add this to your *build.sbt*

```
mappings in Universal <+= (packageBin in Compile, baseDirectory ) map { (_, base) =>
     val conf = base / "conf" / "application.conf"
     conf -> "conf/application.conf"
}
```

This will map your *application.conf* in the *conf* folder. When you build a debian package with

```
debian:packageBin
```

you can see in *target/-/DEBIAN/conffiles* an entry

```
/usr/share/<app-name>/conf/application.conf
```

An **apt-get remove your-app** won't remove this file, only a **purge**

Comment: Unfortunately does not work with universal:packageZipTarball

Comment: And that makes sense. Because tarballs are not a native os packaging format like deb or rpm.